# Mesh inner faces getting exposed with animation

Tags: animation

My character's shoe sole is behaving like this when I animate the feet:

[image]

To be more specific, it happens when I rotate de tip of the feet.

Anyway to stop this from happening?

Comment: hello, maybe correct in Weight Paint mode, or if you want to hide a part of your mesh you can use the Mask modifier

Comment: Will that work when I export it to Unity?

Comment: I don't think the Mask modifier will work, in that case give a correction in Weight Paint mode or simply delete? Actually it's not clear what's happening, what part of the object is overlapping?

Comment: The upper side of the sole is overlapping the lower side.

Comment: do you really need the upper side of the sole? is it not supposed to be always invisible anyway?

Comment: No, I don't. Thanks. lol